# How to test for significance for the Sample Autocorrelation Function?

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, t-test

Could someone confirm what method the author has used here to determine significance?

How do I know what distribution the PACF follows?  If I don't know this how can I do significance testing?

Is it the use of the t-test with test statistic $t = \frac{PACF}{0.032}$? We then check this against the 5% significance level for the t-distribution?

[image]

Comment: As the quotation says, this is an approximate standard error.  (An accurate one varies slightly with the lag and assumes this is a Normal process).  The calculation is simple: $0.032 = \sqrt{1/996}.$  Similarly, I suspect Example 2.1 might involve a series of $176$ observations, for a standard error of $1/\sqrt{176}.$  The general rule is the SE equals the reciprocal square root of the series length.

Comment: @whuber I see, thank you. May I ask if the formulation of this t-test is in fact correct? Is that the way that the author has concluded that only AR(3) and AR(9) are significant?